# Unit circular disk double integral - area of $0$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, area

I'm confused with my attempt of trying to solve:

$$\iint_A (x^2-y^2) \ dA$$

where $A$ is the unit circular disk $r \le 1$.

Now, in my sketch, the function I have is a circle, basically, of radius $1$ centered at the origin. I do hope this isn't the part that messed me up.

My thought process from there:

- I will convert this to polar.
- The order shouldn't matter here - but I will do $R$ first, then $\theta$.
- The limits should be $0 \le R \le 1$ and $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$.

Now integrating:

$$\int_{\theta =0}^{2\pi} \int_{R=0}^1 R^2\cos^2\theta - R^2\sin^2\theta \ R\,dR\,d\theta$$

$$\int_{\theta =0}^{2\pi} \int_{R=0}^1 R^3(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta) \,dR\,d\theta$$

$$\int_{\theta =0}^{2\pi}(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta) \int_{R=0}^1 R^3 \ \,dR\,d\theta$$

$$\left(R^4/4\right)_0^1 = 1/4 - 0 = 1/4$$

$$1/4 \int_{\theta =0}^{2\pi}(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta) \ d\theta$$

$$1/4 \int_{\theta =0}^{2\pi} \cos2\theta \ d\theta$$

$$1/4\left(\frac{\sin2\theta}{2}\right)_0^{2\pi}$$

And this.. ends up being $0$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you're wrong?

Comment: I find the area to be zero to be fishy. Yes, it's centered at the origin but still, I'd find it odd if the area was different depending on what point the circle is centered at.

Comment: You're not calculating area, your calculating the volume under the function $z=x^2-y^2$. From symmetry consideration the volume under $z=x^2$ is equal to the volume under $z=y^2$ for this specific domain of integration, and so it makes sense you end up with zero.

Comment: One thing that's wrong is that you need $$\int_{\theta =0}^{2\pi} \int_{R=0}^1 \left(R^2\cos^2\theta - R^2\sin^2\theta\right) \ R\,dR\,d\theta$$ rather than $$ \int_{\theta =0}^{2\pi} \int_{R=0}^1 R^2\cos^2\theta - R^2\sin^2\theta \ R\,dR\,d\theta. $$ But you corrected that before you finished.

Comment: Also $$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \left(x^2-y^2\right) \, dy \, dx=0$$

Comment: If you do want to calculate the area the integral you'd want to do would be $$\iint_A 1 dA$$

Answer (score 1):

It is not surprising you got zero.  You can break your integral up as 
$$\iint_A (x^2-y^2) \ dA=\iint_A (x^2) \ dA-\iint_A (y^2) \ dA$$
The first integral is the volume under a paraboloid with vertex along the $y$ axis.  The second is the volume under a congruent paraboloid with vertex along the $x$ axis.  The second integral is just a rotation of the first by $\frac \pi 2$, so the values of of the integrals is the same and the difference is zero

Answer (score 0):

That the integral you get should be $0$ can be seen quickly without resorting to polar coordinates. That $\displaystyle \iint\limits_A x^2 \, d(x,y) = \iint\limits_A y^2\, d(x,y)$ follows from the kind of symmetry you have. The region $A$ is symmetric about the line $y=x,$ and reflection about that line consists simply of interchanging the two variables $x$ and $y.$ Thus these two integrals are equal and so their difference is $0.$